# Simple Android Conversion App Not Functioning

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm a bit confused, I set up my app as a simple converter but it isn't working. My log says it has to do with myclickhandler, but I'm not sure where to go with that.

```
  package hmdywifinal.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Butterfliesstart extends Activity {
private ImageButton ConvertButterflies = null;
private ImageButton Butterfliesstart1 = null;
private EditText YourWeight = null;
private TextView Output = null;
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.butterfliesstart);

    //GO BACK
        ImageButton Butterfliesstart1 =      (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.testbutton2);
        Butterfliesstart1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View argo) {
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            };
        });

    //Set IDS
        ImageButton ConvertButterflies = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.testbutton1);


    //Set Values
    class ToButterflies implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            convertToButterflies();
        }
        private void convertToButterflies()
        {
            String ButterflyString = YourWeight.getText().toString();
            double f = Double.parseDouble(ButterflyString);
            double c = 5.0/9.0 * (f - 32.0); 
            EditText YourWeight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            Output.setText(String.valueOf(c));      

        }
    }
    Output = new EditText(this);
    EditText Output = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    //Initialize
    Butterfliesstart1 = new ImageButton(this);
    ConvertButterflies = new ImageButton(this);

    YourWeight = new EditText (this);
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Butterfliesstart"></TextView>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ImageButton 
android:text="and back."  
android:src="@drawable/dirtbutton"
android:id="@+id/testbutton2" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick=""
>
</ImageButton>
<ImageButton
android:src="@drawable/bumblebees"
android:id="@+id/testbutton1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="myClickHandler"
> 
</ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

After I press the button to convert it, it force closes. Did I miss anything in the code?

Comment: try figure our why its crashing by looking at the log instead of posting and saying *it doesn't work*. Learn the basics to debug your application. You can find this information on the dev site. And when you get this learn to read your stacktrace to find the problematic line then try to figure out the condition that is causing it to crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you haven't posted all of it, your `ImageButton` with the id  of `testbutton1` has an `android:onClick` defined as `myClickHandler` but you haven't defined that method. That'll crash quite successfully every time you press it.

I agree with JoxTraex, though... this is pretty easy stuff to track if you take the time to learn to use the tools you have. Read up on DDMS.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this. I did say in my question that I checked the log and  am also using DDMS, but I am still confused over how to implement myClickHandler in Java as well as having another class. Do you think you can help me with this?